# Auto refresh page after submit form - ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, forms, window, electron, reload

I'm looking for a way to auto refresh a window after I submitted a form.
I've tried to use 
`window.on("closed", () => {
window2.reload();
})` 

but it did nothing.
How can I managed to reload my page every time I submit my form ?
My code : [image: Submit form code][image: app.js for my windows][image: An example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found:

Javascript:

```
function AutoRefresh( t ) {
           setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
        }
```

HTML:

```
<body onload = "JavaScript:AutoRefresh(5000);">
<p>This page will refresh every 5 seconds.</p>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks mate ^^ it's working. I can keep this for some times :D.